# Comparing Strings

Tags: python

Does there exist any inbuilt function in python than can return number of  mathching characters in two strings,for example:

INPUT:

```
   TICK TOCK
   CAT DOG
   APPLE APPLES
```

OUTPUT:

```
 3
 0
 5
```

The words "TICK" and "TOCK" have a score of 3, since three characters (T, C, K) are the same. Similarly, "CAT" and "DOG" score 0, since no letters match.

I am a new bie in python so please help me with examples.

Comment: Cant think of anything other than re, for regular expression searching.

Comment: What do you want returned for "CAT TAC"?  That is, does the order of characters in the string matter?  What about "CAT CHAT"?

Comment: What about ABCDEF and BCDEF? 5 or 0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a version using list comprehensions:

```
[x == y for (x, y) in zip("TICK", "TOCK")].count(True)
```

Or, shorter (using `operator`):

```
import operator
map(operator.eq, "TICK", "TOCK").count(True)
```

According to @Kabie, `<expr>.count(True)` can be replaced by `sum(<expr>)` in both versions.

Comment: Could you please explain this solutions?

Comment: The first one creates a list of tuples, each of which contains corresponding characters from the two strings (in the example, `[('T', 'T'), ('I', 'O'), ('C', 'C'), ('K', 'K')]`).  The comprehension then changes each tuple into either `True` or `False` based on whether the characters are equal, and then `count(True)` determines the number of matches.  The second one is similar; `map` applies its first argument (`operator.eq`) to corresponding elements of the other arguments.  The `operator.eq` function is the same as the `==` operator, except that it can be passed to functions like `map`.

Comment: Just `sum(map(operator.eq, "APPLE","APPLES"))`

Comment: @JeremiahWillcock I think you better add that to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in function. But you can do it using some simple expressions,.

```
>>> A, B = sorted("APPLE APPLES".split(), key=len)
>>> len([e for e in A if e in B])
5
```

Comment: Corrected the answer. Sorry guys, overlooked the repetitive part.

Answer (score 1):

If the position *and* order of the characters are important, then the chosen answer would suffice. The problem is, the given solution will not work if that is not the case.

If position is not important, but the order is, you could write a function that returns the length of the [longest common subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence). Here is a sample implementation:

```
def lcs(string1, string2):
    m = len(string1)
    n = len(string2)

    C = [[0] * (n + 1)] * (m + 1)
    for i in range(m + 1)[1:]:
        for j in range(n + 1)[1:]:
            if string1[i - 1] == string2[j - 1]:
                C[i][j] = C[i - 1][j - 1] + 1
            else:
                C[i][j] = max(C[i][j - 1], C[i - 1][j])
    return C[m][n]
```

If position *and* order does not matter, you can use `collections.Counter` (Python 2.7/3.1; or http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611/) like so:

```
def f(string1, string2):
    set_string1 = Counter(string1)
    set_string2 = Counter(string2)

    # get common characters
    common = set_string1 & set_string2

    # return the sum of the number of occurrences for each character
    return reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, common.values())
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you import operator by writing
import **operator**
and use **operator.eq** method like this:

```
import operator

operator.eq(String, String)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help:

```py
def CommonLetters(s1, s2):
    
    l1 = list(''.join(s1.split()))
    l2 = list(''.join(s2.split()))

    return [x for x in l1 if x in l2]

x = CommonLetters('cerberus', 'atorb')
print(len(x))
```

Comment: You could improve the general utility of your answer by providing some more clarification on what the posted code does.